# How to download a file from a HTTP request that doesn't probably doesn't allow cross origin

Tags: javascript, html, http, httprequest, userscripts

I've got some links with this kind of structure https://hostname.com/stuff?u=0&file=/path/file.mp3. What I wanna do is download the files that they redirect me to.

The problem is that visiting directly the link with a web browser doesn't allow me to download it (nor open it), it gives me a blank page. Instead when opening a link from a page on the same site it successfully redirects me to the file. What I'm guessing is that the API doesn't allow any other site (host?) to get the info.

I've tried using userscript to feed the html page with `<a href="">`'s but I want to automate the download procedure for every file. Furthermore I tried to put them in an iframe to make them download automatically but, because they're mp3 files, they just start to play on the page.

Is there a way to do it? Can I "fake" my request to make it look it comes from the right host?

Comment: Check an old fiddle I made :[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mnethL1/4/), it uses `axiosjs` to allow the download. Tell me if that's something you need.

Comment: @Alex Nice! The only problem is that I want it to also name the downloaded file automatically to what the original name is on the server instead of the generic 'file.mp3' that it's giving me. Maybe I can fix it in the function, right?

Comment: Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5mnethL1/20/). Accessed `response.config.url` to retrieve the URL from the promise and used Regex to retrieve the last part of the URL to name the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using regular XHR, you might be able to set the "X-Referer" header, like so `xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Referer', 'https://hostname.com/');`